# Cómo consumir un servicio web con autenticación?

Tags: javascript, ajax, web, webservice

Que tal señores me proporcionaron este consumo de servicio web el cual en postman claro que corre bien, pero en el codigo jQuery con ajax no, el detalle esque tiene autenticacion, y esa es mi duda endonde debo de poner los paramatros usuario y contraseña para poder consumir

````
var settings = {
  "url": "url",
  "method": "POST",
  "timeout": 0,
  "headers": {
    "Authorization": "Basic bWl1c3VhcmlvOm1pcGFzc3dvcmQ=",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Cookie": "incap_ses_9219_2112329=tBfUNf83r0saOD/Iynfwf5mEumAAAAAAUCGCcoBB5bALc9n6mmkcLg==; visid_incap_2112329=BwuJx2lWQoK4FrZ58YVWlXYotF8AAAAAQUIPAAAAAAAlaAydx2GDkrDC4W+syX61"
  },
  "data": JSON.stringify({
    "noContenedor": "qeqeqwerwqer"
  }),
};
 
$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
});
  </script>```
````

Comment: Edite el código porque estabas exponiendo usuario y password

Comment: En POSTMAN haz click en el menu `code` y selecciona `JavaScript Jquery AJAX`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Que tal al fin la solucion al error fue activar el una extension de CORS en el navegador CORS

Comment: Y que relación tiene esto con la pregunta? es decir con la autenticación. Además, cada usuario tiene que "activar una extensión" para que funcione?

Comment: por alguna razon cuando consultas el servicio desde local host, te da error de cors al consultar a un amigo que tiene mas experiencia me compartio la extesion de google chorme, pero esto es solo para el ambito de desarrollo, ya al subirlo al server todo jala bien

Answer (score 0):

La autenticación depende del server, por el código pareciera que la autenticación es el esquema de autorización http [Basic](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization), en esa forma de autenticar se envían las credenciales en el header.

La forma sería `Authorization: Basic HASH` donde HASH es un base64 de `usuario:password` osea que respondiendo a la pregunta, el usuario y password va luego especificar el tipo de esquema (Basic en este caso) y encodeado en base64.

Cuidado que base64 es un algoritmo reversible, no ofrece ningina seguridad en trasporte ni nada, se puede codificar y descodificar facilmente.

Ejémplo el string "miusuario:mipassword" coresponde con el base64 de "bWl1c3VhcmlvOm1pcGFzc3dvcmQ=" y  viceversa. Aqui hay un encoder y decoder https://www.base64encode.org/ pero se puede hacer programaticamente también.